# ListFieldIterator change design for list forms

Tags: list-form

I want to change the design of New Form and Edit Form in SP 2013, I have seen many articles on the internet but all of them talking about trying to hide or display a field based on specific conditions, like this one:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa543922(v=office.14).aspx
http://www.3guysonsharepoint.com/?p=987

I need to change the look and feel of the form to create sections and group fields in these sections in two or three columns layout, how do I do that?